# What occurs when socket's IP changed, and how to deal with it?

Tags: sockets, delphi, tcp, network-programming

I'm developing a C/S program using Delphi 7, TServerSocket and TClientSocket controls. One problem is now I can only use my PC as server, and my PC is using virtual dialer, so ISP keeps changing my IP, about once in one or two days.

Because I'm using a router, the ServerSocket is opened directly in my local IP (192.168.1.x), just mapped to my public IP, so I suppose the ServerSocket itself shouldn't crash when my public IP changes. What I suppose should be: when my IP changes, all connecting sockets become unavailable, and when my application doesn't know it and still using the socket, ServerSocket should receive some event like OnClientError.

But I found a weird problem - when my IP changed, the server application automatically shut down. I don't know exactly what happened because the shut-down time is afternoon, I was in my office, but I noticed another result: even I used heartbeat in my application layer protocol, the server didn't catch the keep-alive failure - because I recorded everything in a log file on my server, and didn't find it. So my server must be shut down instantly when my IP changed, which even didn't reach the keep-alive logic.

This seems very weird, how can a socket error(due to IP change) directly lead to the whole application shut down? Please if someone have any explanations, and how to deal with this problem, thanks

Comment: Without seeing the actual server code it is hard to find out what happens. Can you try to build a very small code example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Did you check the Windows event logs for crash information?

Comment: You can use procdump to create a dump file once the process exits. `procdump -ma -t <yourserverprocess>`. Open the dumpfile with WinDbg and run kv to view the stacktrace of the process exiting.

Comment: The IP change occurs on the public side of the router, not on your server PC. The only ways your app could be exiting when the IP changes is if 1) you have coded your app to exit when a client TCP connection disconnects/fails, or 2) your app is raising an exception that you are not catching and it is taking out your main UI thread. As for the keep-alive issue, either your app is exiting before the keep-alive elapses, or you are not coding your keep-alive correctly. Either way, none of these are socket/TCP issues, they are coding issues on your part. But you did not show any of your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Once the socket is opened, its bound IP address will never change. This can not be 'fixed' on the server side. I would recommend to work on the servers stability, also the clients should detect that the server no longer exists at the given IP address, and re-connect. (This is independent of why the server became unavailable - a restarting server is normal.)

Comment: clients can detect the server doesn't exist at the old address easily by keep-alive. But the problem is there's no way the client can know the new address. However I noticed the server crash isn't due to IP change, but two reasons: a client crash which cause the socket unclosed and OS handled the exception, or the server is too busy and can't handle the network messages in time. I fixed the latter partially by multi-threading, but I still have no answer to the former.